# Error in TAG in Android Studio while using Google Firebase Authentication using Email and Password

Tags: android-layout, firebase, firebase-authentication

### Here is the Code

I have also created A separate function for the still it does not work

```
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: 'TAG' has private access  in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity'

Answer (score 0):

Add codes below

**for Kotlin:**

```
companion object{
        private const val TAG = "your tag"
    }
```

to the out of `onCreate()`

**for Java:**

under your class (I guess it is "EmailPasswordActivity")

```
private static final String TAG = "EmailPassword";
```

That should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Change `TAG` with "yourname". I've tried it and it was successful.